# Why I used DeleteLocalRef(jclass), but still got memory leak in C++

Tags: memory-leaks, jvm, java-native-interface

Here's my exam under Ubuntu/JVM 1.7.0_75

1.
A thread will call the function below 50000 times per-second:

> void LoggerImp::jniLog() {
>       for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
>       {} }

Of course, there's nothing problematic here.

2.
I add some jni codes into it:

> void LoggerImp::jniLog() {
>       for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
>       {
>           jclass tcls = env->FindClass("com/morefun/bi/sdk/UserInfo");
>       } }

O.K. I didn't release the local reference, so memory leak happenes.

3.
Then I added the local reference releasing code as:

> void LoggerImp::jniLog() {
>        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
>        {
>            jclass tcls = env->FindClass("com/morefun/bi/sdk/UserInfo");
>            env->DeleteLocalRef(tcls);
>        } }

Seems no memory leak there...

4.
I make it more loop:

> void LoggerImp::jniLog() {
>        for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
>        {
>            jclass tcls = env->FindClass("com/morefun/bi/sdk/UserInfo");
>            env->DeleteLocalRef(tcls);
>        } }

Horrible things happened, there's still memory leak...
This time, the memory leak is not inside JVM, JVM heap looks O.K. during GC.

The program only use one JVM env in C++, and the code will never return back to JAVA. 
And it's supposed to be a stable server thread, it's very important to keep the memory clean.

This made me crazy.
Anyone has idea on this issue will be very appreciated, :)

Comment: Please explain why you are benchmarking loading and releasing the same class 1000 times. This is not a realistic thing to test.

Comment: What kind of *horrible things* did you see in case 4?

Comment: It's a stupid mistake from myself. The 1000 loop cost too many CPU time, so another thread in the process can not get enough chances to release memory in other place.(I make it in a single-core CPU). So actually there's no memory leak at all. Thanks guys.

Comment: Define "memory leak". what's the exact error that you're getting?